# Efficient Level up after every 10?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make it so that after every say 200 of a value, it will increase a global variable by 1. As you can see below the problem I have is that one, it isn't in any way shape or form efficient and really doesn't work well.

An overall of how I'd like this to work would be so that when **GV.TotalNumberValue** hits past a certain number, let's say 200, **GV.TotalLevel** will increase by one and update the text and this will happen every time that **GV.TotalNumberValue** increases by 200.

Finally, if this is going to be checking what the number is on constantly, should I have this bound to an event such as a button click or a timer? Your help's greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
 void LevelMod()
    {
        if (GV.TotalNumberValue >= 200)
        {
            GV.TotalLevel = GV.TotalLevel + 1;
            lblLevel.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}", GV.LevelPrefix, GV.TotalLevel);
        }
        else if (GV.TotalNumberValue >= 400)
        {
            GV.TotalLevel = GV.TotalLevel + 1;
            lblLevel.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}", GV.LevelPrefix, GV.TotalLevel);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use integer division similar to:

```
void LevelMod()
{
    // I assume the level variables are integrals, so perform an integer division
    if (GV.TotalNumberValue / 200 > GV.TotalLevel)
    {
        GV.TotalLevel = GV.TotalNumberValue / 200;
        lblLevel.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}", GV.LevelPrefix, GV.TotalLevel);
    }
}
```

Essentially, your `TotalLevel` is always `TotalNumberValue / 200`. This assumes that that `GV.TotalNumberValue` is an integral type [which always rounds the result towards zero.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can use simple math:

- Either deduce the level from the value, like this:

  ```
  int totalLevel = value / 200;
  ```

  This works because an integer division is always rounded down.
- Or, if you know that `value` has just been incremented, you can detect a level boundary like this:

  ```
  bool shouldLevelUp = (value % 200) == 0;
  if (shouldLevelUp)
      ++totalLevel;
  ```

Comment: If you skip a value from `199` to `201` for some reason it won't level up. A minor thing maybe or a major bug depends on the rest of the implementation.

Comment: @ja72 Yes, the first solution is the better one IMO. When I was saying *if you know that `value` has just been incremented* I was implying it's always incremented by 1.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks for you input! Appreciate it.